# Mongodb CSV functionality not working

Tags: mongodb

```
 mongoimport -d  ramp -c country --type csv --file http://fromtheramp.com/temp/country.csv --headerline
```

I had use import funtionality on localhost and is working fine. but now, it is not working on server. 
it gives me the following error.

```
Failed: open http://fromtheramp.com/temp/country.csv: no such file or directory
```

http://fromtheramp.com/temp/country.csv file exists but is not getting imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/) utility does not work with external file sources such as a URI resource like you are trying to do.

In order to do what you want, "pipe" the input from another command like `curl` to `mongoimport` instead:

```
curl http://fromtheramp.com/temp/country.csv | \
mongoimport -d  ramp -c country --type csv --headerline
```

Both `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` both work with STDIN/STDOUT as default unless you include an option such as `--file`. So omit that and work with STDIN instead.

As a non-csv example ( same principles apply though ) you can use the publicly accessible mongodb sample data set as a test:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/dataset.json | \
mongoimport -d test -c restaurants --drop
```

Which hapilly imports that data, and a bit more effienctly than the [manual page](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/import-data/) suggests you do it. Though you might want a local copy for testing.